# Series Expanding a Function: Complex Answer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have

$$
f(x)=2\arccos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}
$$

and my friend says that the series of this function about $x=2$ (truncated to the first term) given $x\leq2$ is $$f(x)\approx\frac{4}{3}\left(2-x\right)^{3/2}...$$

but Mathematica (using Series[]) keeps giving me a first term with a non zero complex part: $$f(x)\approx-\frac{4}{3}i\left(x-2\right)^{3/2}...$$
 Is my friend right? How has he obtained his version of the power series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between $\frac 43(2-x)^{3/2}$ and $-\frac43i(x-2)^{3/2}$ is:

1. An overall minus sign.
2. A factor of $i$.
3. The thing raised to the $(3/2)$th power has been negated.

Of these (3) is what causes (2), since $(-1)^{3/2}=\pm i$.

As for (1), the overall sign of the square root of something is not well defined when we're working with complex numbers.

So *each* of the two differently-looking first terms actually have *the same* two possible values.

Comment: you mean <<The thing raised to the ***(3/2)th*** power has been negated.>>?

Comment: @AlexanderGiles: yes, of course.

Comment: OK, I get it now. Cheers for the quick answer :)